# How to Parse String with 4 Decimal Places

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I have a variable in my TeamCity build that looks like this 3.12.2323.0 when I attempt to parse this variable as a string it fails. here is my code:

```
$versionNumber = %build.version.major%.%build.version.minor%.%build.counter%."0"
```

I've also tried

```
$versionNumber = %build.version.major%+%build.version.minor%+%build.counter%+"0"
```

my error is:

```
Unexpected token '.1682' in expression or statement.
[19:40:18][Step 2/2] At line:1 char:27
[19:40:18][Step 2/2] + $versionNumber = 3.13.1682 <<<< ."0"
[19:40:18][Step 2/2]     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (.1682:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
[19:40:18][Step 2/2]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
[19:40:18][Step 2/2]
```

Comment: Try this: $versionNumber = "{0}{1}{2}.0" -f %build.version.major%, %build.version.minor%, %build.counter%

Comment: `$versionNumber = [Version]'3.13.1682.0'`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with TeamCity, but assuming that `%build.version.major%` et al. are environment variables you could build your version string like this:

```psh
$versionNumber = '{0}.{1}.{2}.0' -f ${env:build.version.major},
                 ${env:build.version.minor}, ${env:build.counter}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks PetSerAl and jisaak I used a mixed of both of your suggestions and it works.

the answer:

```
$versionNumber = '{0}.{1}.{2}.0' -f %build.version.major%,%build.version.minor%,%build.counter%
```